# can't delete old south migrations from heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I made many changes in my django app and when working locally i reset the database, deleted the migration and reseted south, recreated everything all over and it worked fine.
when trying to do the same in Heroku,
after droping the database using:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

and also reseting south using:

```
heroku run ./manage.py reset south
```

and then pushing the Django app when looking at the heroku migration list using:

```
heroku run ./manage.py migrate --list
```

i can still see all of the old imgration,
though they are empty-- no * in the ()
so even after doing

```
heroku run python ./manage.py migrate accounts --fake
```

i still get migration errors:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/accounts/userprofile/

****relation "accounts_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "accounts_userprofile"****
```

what can i do to solve it? is there a wayy to remove old migrations in heroku and just do it simple like when working locally by starting all over again?
or is their any other solution?

Comment: I think `--fake` is used when the database tables already exists and you no longer need to actually migrate the real database. If the tables doesn't exist, you should just run `migrate` without `--fake`.

Comment: Thanks :) website is back!

Comment: Great. I'll add this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--fake` is used when the database tables already exists and you no longer need to actually migrate the real database. As the tables don't exist, you should just run `migrate` without `--fake`.